# MongoDB: Why doesn't this stored JS function return a value?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, stored-procedures, stored-functions

Consider this dummy function:

```
db.system.js.save({
    _id:"findId", 
    value:function(){
        var doc = db.test.find({"_id": "1"})
        return doc['_id']
    }
    })
```

When running it, I get nothing in return.

However, if I just `return db.test.find({"_id": "1"})` I do get the document.

What's the difference?

**The broader question: Can I execute arbitrary JS code on server-side?**

For example, I'd like to retrieve a document and have some if-else logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.test.find({"_id": "1"})` returns `Promise`, and you are not waiting for it to resolve before returning the data. So, when you return `doc['_id']`, `doc` is `undefined`. So, you should return the value after the Promise resolves. You can do it like this:

```
db.test.find({"_id": "1"}).then((document) => {
  return document .id;
})
```